# How to persist CognitoUser during signIn with CUSTOM_AUTH authentication flow

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

My React Native app uses Amplify for a `CUSTOM_AUTH` authentication flow. The user receives a link via email to satisfy a challengeAnswer request. The process is like this:

User initiatiates sign in:

```
const cognitoUser = await Auth.signIn(username);
```

Email is sent to user via lambda.

User leaves app to retrieve email.

User clicks a link in the email which routes user back to the app via the RN `Linking` api.

The code from the link is processed with:

```
await Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(
  cognitoUser,
  authChallengeAnswer
);
```

Usually this works well, but there is no guarantee that the `cognitoUser` object will exist after the app has been backgrounded while the user retrieves the email. There is a non-zero chance that iOS could dump the app during this time, and the `cognitoUser` var would be gone forcing the user to restart the sign in process. I'm looking for a way to persist the `cognitoUser` object somehow so if iOS decides the app needs to die this var can be retrieved from cache.

I'm able to cache the object into the Amplify cache (AsyncStorage) with

```
await Cache.setItem("cognitoUser", cognitoUser);
```

then fetch with

```
await Cache.getItem("cognitoUser");
```

which fails with

> TypeError: user.sendCustomChallengeAnswer is not a function

because the process of caching it lost all its `__proto__` functions. Its just retrieved as a basic object.

I suspect the cause is that I'm not using TypeScript, and the object loses some type information somehow.

Is there a better way of persisting this CognitoUser object so I can guarantee it exists after the user leaves/returns to the app as is needed in a `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow.

Comment: Have you tried Realm ? And are you using redux ?

Comment: This app doesn't use either of those. If possible I'd like to solve this within the Amplify ecosystem of apis. This seems like a common use-case that should be solvable.

Comment: Realm offers object persistence , you can try that instead of async storage ! Just a suggestion

Comment: I'm using redux-persist but not working for me at the moment. Same error as you @Fook

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @farminf Unfortunately I have not. Hoping someone will chime in with an answer!

Comment: Did anyone find the answer ?

Comment: checkout this thread: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1896

Comment: @sachingupta added new answer with solution

Answer (score 6):

I use the following code to persist CognitoUser during sign in with CUSTOM_AUTH authentication flow:

```js
import Auth from '@aws-amplify/auth'
import { CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

const CUSTOM_AUTH_TTL = 5 * 60 * 1000 // Milliseconds

interface CustomAuthSession {
  username: string
  session: string
  // Milliseconds after epoch
  expiresAt: number
}

function clearCustomAuthSession() {
  window.localStorage.removeItem('CustomAuthSession')
}

function loadCustomAuthSession(): CognitoUser {
  const raw = window.localStorage.getItem('CustomAuthSession')
  if (!raw) {
    throw new Error('No custom auth session')
  }
  const storedSession: CustomAuthSession = window.JSON.parse(raw)
  if (storedSession.expiresAt < window.Date.now()) {
    clearCustomAuthSession()
    throw new Error('Stored custom auth session has expired')
  }
  const username = storedSession.username
  // Accessing private method of Auth here which is BAD, but it's still the
  // safest way to restore the custom auth session from local storage, as there
  // is no interface that lets us do it.
  // (If we created a new user pool object here instead to pass to a
  // CognitoUser constructor that would likely result in hard to catch bugs,
  // as Auth can assume that all CognitoUsers passed to it come from its pool
  // object.)
  const user: CognitoUser = (Auth as any).createCognitoUser(username)
  // Session is not exposed to TypeScript, but it's a public member in the
  // JS code.
  ;(user as any).Session = storedSession.session
  return user
}

function storeCustomAuthSession(cognitoUser: CognitoUser) {
  // Session isn't exposed to TypeScript, but it's a public member in JS
  const session = (cognitoUser as any).Session
  const expiresAt = window.Date.now() + CUSTOM_AUTH_TTL
  const otpSession: CustomAuthSession = {
    session,
    expiresAt,
    username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
  }
  const json = window.JSON.stringify(otpSession)
  window.localStorage.setItem('CustomAuthSession', json)
}
```

Comment: Using a private method seems dangerous, as you have noted. Not sure if that would pass our code review. WIth that said, it looks like you are persisting metadata from the `cognitoUser`, then rebuilding a new `cognitoUser` object manually. I like that approach and will experiment with it. Really hoping to find a public api for this though. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: Thanks very much! The ideia of recreate the object CognitoUser works nicely for us!

Answer (score 0):

You can reconstruct the `CognitoUser` object manually from your serialized object in localStorage or cache:

```
import { CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const pool = new CognitoUserPool({
      UserPoolId: cognitoObject.pool.userPoolId,
      ClientId: cognitoObject.pool.clientId,
      endpoint: cognitoObject.client.endpoint,
      Storage: window.localStorage,
      AdvancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag: cognitoObject.advancedSecurityDataCollectionFlag,
})
const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
      Username: cognitoObject.username,
      Pool: pool,
      Storage: window.localStorage,
})

cognitoUser.Session = cognitoObject.Session

await Auth.completeNewPassword(cognitoUser, newPassword, cognitoObject.challengeParams)
```

Had to add the `import` statement myself, but got the general idea here: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/1715#issuecomment-800999983

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and the simplest solution was to store it as a global variable within the slice.

authSlice.ts:

```js
    // we use this to temporarily store CognitoUser for MFA login.
    // CognitoUser is not serializable so we cannot store it on Redux.
    let cognitoUser = {};
    
    
    export const doLogin = createAsyncThunk(
      "auth/login",
      async ({ email, password }: UserCredentials): Promise<Login | MFA> => {
        const res = await Auth.signIn(email, password);
        if (res.challengeName === "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA") {
          // we use this to temporarily store CognitoUser for MFA login.
          // CognitoUser is not serializable so we cannot store it on Redux.
          cognitoUser = res;
          return {
            status: "MFA",
            user: null,
          };
        } else {
          const user = await getUser();
          return { user, status: "OK" };
        }
      }
    );
    
    
    export const confirmMFA = createAsyncThunk("auth/confirmMFA", async ({ mfa }: UserMFA) => {
      if (!cognitoUser) {
        throw new Error("Invalid flow?!");
      }
      await Auth.confirmSignIn(cognitoUser, mfa, "SOFTWARE_TOKEN_MFA");
      const user = await getUser();
      return { user, status: "OK" };
    });
    
    
    
    const getUser = async (): Promise<User> => {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      // @ts-ignore https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4927
      const { accessToken } = session;
      if (!accessToken) {
        throw new Error("Missing access token");
      }
      setCredentials(accessToken.jwtToken);
      const user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
      return user.attributes;
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Our requirement was also the same and we managed to get the customAuth flow working by creating cognitoUserPool and cognitoUser instance from localStorage/sessionStorage before calling sendCustomChallengeAnswer.

Example:

```
const userPoolData = {
Attributes: values(from localStorage);
}
const cognitoUserPool = new CognitoUserPool(userPoolData);

const userData = {
Attributes: values(from localStorage);
}

const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);

Auth.sendCustomChallengeAnswer(cognitoUser, validationCode);
```

Comment: Shouldn't create new `CognitoUserPool` as that can interfere with internal user pool of `Auth`